Unexpected character in JSON response when running flutterfire configure
I have installed firebase CLI and Node.JS and and made sure that firebase CLI is up to date. I ran dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli, which worked, but when I tried to run flutterfire configure this was the result:
PS E:\Flutter Projects\chat_app> flutterfire configure
⠏ Fetching available Firebase projects...
Failed to parse JSON response from Firebase CLI. JSON response:
>
FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 2, character 1)
>
^

PS E:\Flutter Projects\chat_app>

I tried to log out and log in again to firebase which didn't work, and I tried to reinstall firebase CLI too.

On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.
